I accidentally dropped a lamp on my gecko and now she is walking without back legs. I what do I do?
I was feeding my niece's female gecko while she was on a trip. Then all of a sudden the heat lamp I was holding, fell into the cage onto her. She is now dragging her hind legs and I don't know what I did to her and I don't know what to do.
Do they heal themselves? Will she be able to walk again? I'm so worried and unsure if I can afford the vet. I’ve kept her in the right condition and fed her but I want to help her more.

Sounds like spinal damage and I honestly don't know if a vet can do anything to help. I hope that another user with more experience will chime in.
In the best case scenario there's just a swelling that presses on the nerves. Once the swelling goes down, mobolity of the legs should return.
In the worst case scenario the spinal cord is severed. Amphibians do have better cell regeneration than mammals, but any nerve damage usually takes several weeks to heal and must not be re-damaged by movement in this time. It's honestly very unlikely (but not impossible) to get better in this case.
The best you can do right now is keep her at ideal conditions and (if possible) remove any climbing opportunities so that she cannot fall down.
